# Angular 5 http service response error

Tags: xml, angular, http, service, rss

I'm trying to consume http RSS service with an xml response.

I get response status OK(200) with the following error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad ..

What I'm doing wrong, and how can I parse an xml response?

Component.ts Code:

```
this.ns.nBasicApi().subscribe((jsonFromServer) => { 
  this.response = jsonFromServer;
});
```

Service Code:

```
nBasicApi():any {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/stocks');
}
```

Server code App.js:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Accept,Accept- 
Language,Content-Language,Content-Type');
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers','Content- 
Length,Content-Range');
next();
})
app.route('/api/stocks').get((req, res) => {
 fetch('http://www.nasdaq.com/aspxcontent/NasdaqRSS.aspx? 
data=quotes&symbol=NFLX').then((res) => { 
         return res.text();
 }).then((json) => {
     res.send(json)
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way in Angular to parse XML as far as I know, so you'll need to find some library and `map` response. Angular by default treats responses as JSON, so there is your parse error. To disable automatic parsing use `{responseType: 'text'}`

```
nBasicApi():any {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/stocks', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

Comment: Correct. Angular doesn't recognize XMLs by default, but by doing your trick of `{responseType: 'text'}` you are just telling the observable that you are pasing some string then he will have to convert the xml to a json manually

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't support XML. Angular supports json by defeault. Try to use a npm package like the one below

**npm install xml2js -g**
import in service file as : `import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';`

example

```
let formdata = new URLSearchParams();
formdata.set('username','username');
formdata.set('pw','pw'); 
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: RequestMethod.Post});

postData () {

     this.http.post(this._yourUrl, formdata.toString(), options)
     //convert to JSON here
     .map(res => {
            xml2js.parseString( res.text(), function (err, result) {
            console.dir(result); // Prints JSON object!
         });
     })
     .subscribe(data => { 
          console.log(data);              
     });
}
```

or Take a look to this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gkxucxrj/1/